# Javascript attribute is NaN

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript code:

```
var Environment = function() {
    this.road_frame_id = 1;   
}

Environment.prototype.nextRoadFrame = function() {
    if((this.road_frame_id -= 1) < 1) { 
        this.road_frame_id = 3;
    }
    document.getElementById("road").setAttribute("src", "images/road_background_" + this.road_frame_id + ".png");
}

var environment = new Environment();
setInterval(environment.nextRoadFrame, 150);
```

But it seems that inside the function nextRoadFrame the attribute this.road_frame_id as the value NaN, when it should be 3. Why is this happening?

Thanks

Comment: "this" is the window in nextRoadFrame. remember that this depends on the context, which at the point where you pass the function to setInterval, is the window obj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing the function stored in `environment.nextRoadFrame` but without any context, so the value of `this` will be `window` when it is called.

Create a new function that calls your function with the right context and pass that to `setInterval`.

```
setInterval(environment.nextRoadFrame.bind(environment), 150);
```

See the [documentation for `bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for compatibility and alternatives.

Comment: Maybe nit picking, but "calls…with the right context" might be better as "sets *this* to the expected value" (the word "context" isn't used in the referenced article or the description of [*bind* in ECMA-262](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5)). In strict mode, *this* can be any value (and in the OP would be *undefined*), and *context* in relation to a function is more appropriately applied to [*execution context*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4).